# Optimization of ash stockpile height to minimize haul truck fuel costs

Tags: materials, civil-engineering, design

How would I find out the optimum height of an ash stockpile in order to minimize diesel haulage costs, for a CAT haul truck?

My stockpile height is required to be between 25m to 50m.

I have worked out the fuel consumption and time taken from the start point to the haulage area, based on required speeds obtained from the rimpull-speed-gradeability curves for that particular CAT truck. But I'm not sure how to relate this to the calculating the optimum stockpile height?

Comment: Check out that question about piling sand and the angle... Also check out Aberfan...

Comment: @SUser: You're on an international site where many (including me) don't know what an ash stockpile is (some sort of boiler fuel waste?) and what the other constraints are as, obviously, hauling it up only 25 m would require less energy so there must be something else that prevents you doing this by default. There's an edit link below your question ...

Comment: In addition to the comment by *Transistor*, how will the stockpile be created? Will the trucks drive on the stockpile to dump their loads?